# Парсинг без библиотек на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

У меня есть вот такая строка и её нужно распарсить без использования библиотек только средствами самого python 3:

```
command s1 s2 (l1 l2) [lp 990] (l [li p]) "entity j [90 90]" <ping 90> *9 9* lol
```

Нужно получить:

```
['command', 's1', 's2', {'strings': ['l1', 'l2'], type: 'round_brackets'}, {'strings': ['lp', '990'], type: 'square_brackets'}, {'strings': ['l', {'strings': ['li', 'p'], type: 'square_brackets'}], type: 'round_brackets'}, {'strings': 'entity j [90 90]', type: 'quotes'}, {'strings': ['ping', '90'], type: 'command'}, {'integers': ['9', '9'], type: 'nums'}, 'lol']
```

Правила парсинга:

1. скобки и кавычки и звёзды могут быть вложенными
2. в кавычках не работает парсинг.
3. в звёздах вместо string integer.
4. в полученном массиве в его словарях будет само содержание и тип.

Это всё нужно сделать, кто может сделайте пожалуйста :).

И я **НЕ** смог написать парсер с помощью словарей в списках.

Comment: осталось показать код, который вы уже написали

Comment: Это учебное задание?

Comment: Нет это для моего проекта удалённого доступа.

Comment: Команды парсить.

Comment: Поможете пожалуйста :)

Comment: давайте я начну -  https://regex101.com/r/zEnDIX/1

Comment: Спасибо за регулярку, но мне надо по примеру сверху. Со словарями и списками и типами.

Comment: И желательно без регулярок а с циклом for и enumerate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def f(s):
    start = 0
    bracket = None
    array = []
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if bracket:
            if s[i] == ")]>*\""[bracket[1]]:
                array.append(s[start:i + 1].strip())
                start = i + 1
                bracket = None
            continue
        if s[i] in "([<*\"":
            if s[start:i].strip():
                array.extend(s[start:i].split())
            start = i
            bracket = s[i], "([<*\"".index(s[i])
    
    if s[start:].strip():
        array.extend(s[start:].strip().split())
    
    result = []
    for el in array:
        if el[0] not in "([<*\"":
            result.append(el)
        elif el[0] == "\"":
            result.append({
                "strings": el[1:-1],
                "type": "quotes",
            })
        elif el[0] == "*":
            result.append({
                "integers": list(map(int, f(el[1:-1]))),
                "type": "nums",
            })
        else:
            type_ = {
                "(": "round_brackets",
                "[": "square_brackets",
                "<": "command",
            }[el[0]]
            
            result.append({
                "strings": f(el[1:-1]),
                "type": type_,
            })

    return result

s = '''command s1 s2 (l1 l2) [lp 990] (l [li p]) "entity j [90 90]" <ping 90> *9 9* lol'''
print(f(s))
```

Comment: Как обрабатываются вложеные скобки?

Comment: @Danis Всё правильно но в integers должны быть целые числа

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy в втором цикле я вызываю функцию ещё раз `result.append({
                "strings": f(el[1:-1])`

Comment: @Danis         Сможешь объяснить как работает чтобы я лишний раз не задавал вопросы, пожалуйста :).

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Что такое ТС?

Comment: @Danis Спасибо огромнейшие тебе за ответ, очень помог.

Comment: TC - автор вопроса.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Помоги пожалуйста. Объясните как работает и та статья не для вас была. Я знаю что есть вот это https://pythontutor.com/, но я не понимаю как она работает.

Comment: Так точно и подробно проработаны функциональные требования. Есть и не функциональные требования, странные для самостоятельной работы. Нет ни строчки кода. Есть просьба объяснить как это работает, что странно для достаточно простого кода на языке который знает автор вопроса. Что мне думать по поводу такого сочетания? Что это учебное задание, которое делает человек плохо знающий задачу и язык для сдачи на зачёте. Извини если я ошибся.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Мне нужно было время, я понял как оно работает даже добавил %% (процент) на паркинг и убрал * (звезду). Перед этим я посидел в https://pythontutor.com/ минут так 10 и всё понял.